# Siri Shortcuts how do I sequence the results from JSON in a Siri Shortcut?

Tags: ios, arrays, api, shortcut, siri

I'm using the ptv api call for departures and can successfully return back three results.  I'm trying to get Siri to dictate these to me in order but am not having much luck.

When the api is called it returns a bunch of information in an array for however many services you specify (three in my case), but I only want one of the lines to be dictated (scheduled_departure_utc), not the full array.

And I want to pull just this one line out of each of the three blobs of data that are returned so that Siri says...

the next trains to the city are (scheduled_departure_utc),(scheduled_departure_utc),(scheduled_departure_utc).  Where (scheduled_departure_utc) is a short form of time (8:28am, 8:38am, 8:58am) as an example.

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you include a simplified example of your request and the received response?

Comment: I figured out that I needed to replace the Z and T characters that were returned with nothing (so that Siri would not announce them); also that I needed to add a number of hours for my timezone as the results being returned are in UTC.  I ended up setting the results returned from the api call as a variable, then repeating the text replacement and time adjustment for each value returned for my scheduled departure time and adding the translated elements as another variable.  Works a treat now :)